# WebElement.clear() fires javascript change event - Alternatives?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium IDE to initially record the tests and save them as Java WebDriver tests.

When I go into an input field, delete all the text and enter a new value, it records that as 2 commands:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("johnnyleitrim");
```

One problem with this for me is that the clear() event fires a Javascript change event for the "username" field.  This does not happen when I use the browser itself - it waits until the field loses focus before firing the change javascript event, and that's what I want to emulate in Selenium.

The reason I need this is that I do validation on the change() event, and when change is called with an empty value, it displays an alert telling the user the information is invalid - and this alert stops Selenium

So how do I clear the field without using `WebElement.clear()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a [known Selenium bug](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=214).  There were a few options as workarounds mentioned on the bug page, but they all meant having to "heavily" modify the code returned from Selenium IDE.  Instead, I decided to create a Proxy which would do the work for me without too much modification to the IDE generated code:

```
protected WebElement findElement(By criteria) {
    try {
        WebElementHandler webElementHander = new WebElementHandler(seleniumWebDriver.findElement(criteria));
        return (WebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{WebElement.class}, webElementHander);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        logger.error("Could not find " + criteria + " on page " + seleniumWebDriver.getCurrentUrl());
        throw e;
    }
}

private class WebElementHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private WebElement proxiedElement;

    private WebElementHandler(WebElement proxiedElement) {
        this.proxiedElement = proxiedElement;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().equals("clear")) {
            Keys[] keys = new Keys[proxiedElement.getAttribute("value").length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
                keys[i] = Keys.BACK_SPACE;

            proxiedElement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(keys));
            return null;
        }
        return method.invoke(proxiedElement, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid using the `clear()` method and use the `Actions` class to clear and set text in one go, therefore firing the `onchange()` event only once the text is set.

Call the below method like:

```
ClearAndSetText(By.id("username"),"johnnyleitrim");
```

The method clicks the element, selects the existing text using shift+home keys,clears using backspace, and then types in the new text - just like how a user would do.

```
public void ClearAndSetText(By by, string text)
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
    Actions navigator = new Actions(driver);
    navigator.click(element)
        .sendKeys(Keys.END)
        .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
        .sendKeys(Keys.HOME)
        .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
        .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        .sendKeys(text)
        .perform();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fix! I created this issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1841

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using `JavaScriptExecutor` (although I haven't tested it).

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"input[id='username']\").value = ''");
```