# Selenium: element.clear() triggers javascript before sendKeys()

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have an input field that should contain a date.

Suppose the form is loaded with a value inside of the field, e.g. "2015/04/28". I'm using webdriver to select the element using By, then I do:

```
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("2015/04/29");
```

Unfortunately when I clear the element, it triggers some javascript that loads a template "yyyy/MM/dd" and puts that in the field, so when the sendKeys() comes along, the endresult is "yyyy/MM/dd2015/04/29".

This does not happen when you manually perform the steps, if you go to the field and select everything inside it and delete it, it does not load the template *until* you switch to a different element.

So the javascript seems to be triggered not simply by changing the field but combined with something like loss of focus. I have tried a number of ways to focus on the input element:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();
element.click()
element.sendKeys("")    // before the other sendKeys
```

And yet the same thing keeps happening when I use the webdriver.
So two questions:

- how do you in general handle an async javascript call that is triggered by an action you perform but may impact what you are doing? Wait?
- in this particular issue it *seems* to be focus-driven, is there some way that the field is losing focus between clear() and sendKeys()?

**UPDATE**

To elaborate: it is a "text" input field which has a javascript method running on "change", "blur" and "focus" that updates the field value.

So I run `element.clear()` which *must* trigger one of these three because after the clear the code inserts the template data.

By the time I get to element.sendKeys() the damage is done.

So somehow, in between clear() and sendKeys() either "change", "blur" or "focus" is called on the website, the most logical explanation for me is that the field loses focus somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833728/webelement-clear-fires-javascript-change-event-alternatives) which links to a [selenium bug](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=214) which is unfortunately set to "WorkingAsIntended".

Basically: the `clear()` triggers a `change` event.

My solution (based on an answer in the above post) is:

```
    Actions navigator = new Actions(driver);
    navigator.click(element)
        .sendKeys(Keys.END)
        .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
        .sendKeys(Keys.HOME)
        .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
        .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        .perform();
```

After which I do the `element.sendKeys()`

Answer (score 3):

You could try clearing the input by sending backspace.

```
public static void clearWithBackspace(WebElement input) {
    while(input.getAttribute("value").length() > 0) {
        input.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    }
}
```

(or some variation where you send the correct amount of `BACK_SPACE`s followed by the text you want in a single `sendKeys` invocation.)

Or alternatively, set the input value with JavaScript executed by [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

**how do you in general handle an async javascript call**

I wait. Either some estimated amount or if I want to be specific: execute my own script and wait for the completion of that. This works because JavaScript's event loop will execute your script only when everything else is already done. Something like this:

```
public static void waitForScriptExecution() {
    executeJs("var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.innerHTML = 'window.allDone = true;'; document.body.appendChild(sc);");
    int maxWait = 6000;
    int waitTimeSoFar = 0;
    int waitIntervalMs = 500;
    do {
        if (executeJs("return window.allDone").equals("true")) {
            break;
        }
        waitFor(waitIntervalMs, MILLISECONDS);
        waitTimeSoFar = waitTimeSoFar + waitIntervalMs;
    } while (waitTimeSoFar < maxWait);
    if (waitTimeSoFar >= maxWait) {
        // TODO handle timeout
    }
}

public static String executeJs(String script) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Object result = js.executeScript(script);
    return result != null ? result.toString() : null;
}

public static void waitFor(long count, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(timeUnit.toMillis(count));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out, might help.
similar to what ekuusela suggested,
But you can try Ctrl + A and then type.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/OqRAQmmABJY

Adding examples here for completeness,

```
 element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), value));
 element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.END, Keys.BACKSPACE, Keys.BACKSPACE, ... (enough backspaces to erase the field)), value)).
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem myself a couple of weeks back. The thing is i only encountered the problem on occasion. Solved it by enclosing the process in a while loop, retrieving the date after sendkeys() is sent. Then comparing the retrieved date to a regex, if the date doesn't match the regex then i repeat the clear() -> sendKeys() actions again.

To answer your first question, i use a custom method which waits until the number of active requests == 0. Not sure on your second question.